# tox tests, use setup.py extra_require as tox deps source

Tags: python, testing, setup.py, tox

I want to use setup.py as the authority on packages to install for testing, done with extra_requires like so:

```
setup(
    # ...
    extras_require={
        'test': ['pytest', ],
    },
)
```

Tox only appears to be capable of [installing from a requirements.txt](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#depending-on-requirements-txt) file which just implies a step of snapshotting requirements before testing (which I'm ignorant how to do automatically) or by [duplicating the test dependencies](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-deps=MULTI-LINE-LIST) into the tox file, which is all I want to avoid. [One mailing list post](http://lists.idyll.org/pipermail/testing-in-python/2015-March/006285.html) suggested that tox.ini should be the authority on test dependencies, but I don't wish to straightjacket tox into the project that completely.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You now have the "extras" option:

```
# tox.ini
...
[testenv]
...
extras = test
```

Source: https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#extras

Comment: "New in version 2.4.", "2.4 tagged on Oct 12, 2016", so its not brand new, but it sounds like exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the "[extras](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-extras)" option can't resolve the problem (e.g. when your extras dependency requires a dependency from the `deps` section; for example when you use `pytest-django` and your extras dependency doesn't install Django itself).

In that case you can simply install your extras in the `deps` section like this:

```
# tox.ini
[testenv]
deps = .[test]
```

The period `.` represents the current project (current path), followed by the extras in brackets, as usual. This works just like a `pip install .[test]` would.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a nasty hack that seems to work

```
# tox.ini
...
[testenv]
...
install_command = pip install {opts} {packages} {env:PWD}[test]
```

The defualt `install_command` is `pip install {opts} {packages}`, unfortunately `{packages}` is a required argument. Additionally tox doesn't expose the project directory as a magic variable; but it does expose the `env` of  the shell that ran it.

This works by assuming you ran `tox` from the same directory as your `setup.py` and `tox.ini`, and assuming your shell exposes `PWD` as your current path. Tox appears to use something like `shlex` to split your `install_command` into a shell-safe set of arguments, so we cant do things like `{packages}[test]`. Ultimately this hack will name your package twice, but I think that's okay since `{env:PWD}[test]` names your package plus the `extra_require` block you want.

I don't know a better way, the [PYPA SampleProject](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/) seems content with specifying your test dependencies in both setup.py and tox.ini.

Comment: I suppose maybe I should just accept a living requirements.txt.